# Overall winner of a series of Rock Paper Scissors games

Tags: java

I'm creating a Rock Paper Scissor program. At the end, I want it to determine the winner of all games played. It always prints out "Player1 beat Player2 and I" regardless of whoever has the highest score. Where is my mistake and how should I correct it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RPS2Player{
   public static void main(String[]args){
      int onePlay, computerPlay, twoPlay, game = 0, win1 = 0, win2 = 0, compWin = 0, lose1 = 0, lose2 = 0, compLose = 0, playChoice;

      //instantiate objects Scanner and Random
      Scanner UI = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random num = new Random();

      //Get user input: Rock = 0, Paper = 1, Scissors = 2
      System.out.println("Hello! would you like to play Rock, Paper, Scissors? 0=yes, 1=no");
      playChoice = UI.nextInt(2);
      while (playChoice == 0){
         game++;
         System.out.println("Round " + game);
         System.out.println("Player1, choose 0=Rock, 1=Paper, 2=Scissors");
            onePlay = UI.nextInt(3);
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Player2, choose =Rock, 1=Paper, 2=Scissors");
            twoPlay = UI.nextInt(3);

         //get computer generated input: 0, 1, 2
         computerPlay = num.nextInt(3);//defines a random choice of 0, 1, or 2

         switch(onePlay){
            case 0: System.out.println("Player1 chose Rock"); break;
            case 1: System.out.println("Player1 chose Paper"); break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Player1 chose Scissors"); break;
         }//end switch statement for onePlay

         switch (twoPlay){
            case 0: System.out.println("Player2 chose Rock"); break;
            case 1: System.out.println("Player2 chose Paper"); break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Player2 chose Scissors"); break;
         }//end switch statement for twoPlay

         switch(computerPlay){
            case 0: System.out.println("I chose Rock"); break;
            case 1: System.out.println("I chose Paper"); break;
            case 2: System.out.println("I chose Scissors"); break;
         }//end switch statement for computerPlay

         //comparisons Player1 vs computer
         if (onePlay == 0){//Rock
            if (computerPlay == 0){
               System.out.println("Player 1 and I tie!"); 
               //computer chose rock - tie game
            }
            if (computerPlay == 1){ 
               System.out.println("I beat Player1!");
               lose1++;
               compWin++;//computer chose paper - computer wins
            }
            if (computerPlay == 2){
               System.out.println("Player1 beat me!"); 
               compLose++;
               win1++;//computer chose scissors - player wins
            }
         }//end if statements for onePlay = 0 (Rock)

         if (onePlay == 1){//Paper
            if (computerPlay == 0){
               System.out.println("Player1 beat me!"); 
               compLose++;
               win1++;//computer chose rock - player win1s
            }
            if (computerPlay == 1){
               System.out.println("Player1 and I tie!"); 
               // computer chose paper - tie game
            }
            if (computerPlay ==2){
               System.out.println("I beat Player 1!"); 
               lose1++;
               compWin++;//computer chose scissor - computer win1s
            }
         }//end if statements for onePlay = 1 (Paper)

         if (onePlay == 2){//Scissors
            if (computerPlay == 0){
               System.out.println("I beat Player1!"); 
               lose1++;
               compWin++;//computer chose rock - computer wins
            }
            if (computerPlay == 1){
               System.out.println("Player1 beat me!");
               compLose++;
               win1++;//computer chose paper - play wins
            }
            if (computerPlay == 2){
               System.out.println("Player1 and I tie!"); 
               //computer chose scissors - tie game
            }
         }//end if statements for onePlay = 2 (Scissors)
         //end comparisons Player1 vs computer

         //comparisons Player2 vs computer
         if (twoPlay == 0){//Rock
            if (computerPlay == 0){
               System.out.println("Player2 and I tie!"); 
               //computer chose rock - tie game
            }
            if (computerPlay == 1){ 
               System.out.println("I beat Player2!"); 
               lose2++;
               compWin++;//computer chose paper - computer wins
            }
            if (computerPlay == 2){
               System.out.println("Player2 beat me!"); 
               compLose++;
               win2++;//computer chose scissors - player2 wins
            }
         }//end if statements for twoPlay = 0 (Rock)

         if (twoPlay == 1){//Paper
            if (computerPlay == 0){
               System.out.println("Player2 beat me!"); 
               compLose++;
               win2++;//computer chose rock - player wins
            }
            if (computerPlay == 1){
               System.out.println("Player2 and I tie!"); 
               // computer chose paper - tie game
            }
            if (computerPlay ==2){
               System.out.println("I beat Player2!"); 
               lose2++;
               compWin++;//computer chose scissor - computer wins
            }
         }//end if statements for twoPlay = 1 (Paper)

         if (twoPlay == 2){//Scissors
            if (computerPlay == 0){
               System.out.println("I beat Player2!"); 
               lose2++;
               compWin++;//computer chose rock - computer wins
            }
            if (computerPlay == 1){
               System.out.println("Player2 beat me!");
               compLose++;
               win2++;//computer chose paper - player2 wins
            }
            if (computerPlay == 2){
               System.out.println("Player2 and I tie!"); 
               //computer chose scissors - tie game
            }
         }//end if statements for twoPlay = 2 (Scissors)
         //end comparisons Player2 vs computer

         //comparison Player1 vs Player2
         if (onePlay == 0){//Rock
            if (twoPlay == 0){
               System.out.println("Player1 and Player2 tie!"); 
               //Player2 chose rock - tie game
            }
            if (twoPlay == 1){ 
               System.out.println("Player2 beat Player1!"); 
               lose1++;
               win2++;//Player2 chose paper - Player2 wins
            }
            if (twoPlay == 2){
               System.out.println("Player1 beat Player2!"); 
               lose2++;
               win1++;//Player2 chose scissors - player1 wins
            }
         }//end if statements for personPlay = 0 (Rock)

         if (onePlay == 1){//Paper
            if (twoPlay == 0){
               System.out.println("Player1 beat Player2!"); 
               lose2++;
               win1++;//computer chose rock - player wins
            }
            if (twoPlay == 1){
               System.out.println("Player1 and Player2 tie!"); 
               // computer chose paper - tie game
            }
            if (twoPlay ==2){
               System.out.println("Player2 beat Player1!"); 
               lose1++;
               win2++;//player2 chose scissor - player2 wins
            }
         }//end if statements for personPlay = 1 (Paper)

         if (onePlay == 2){//Scissors
            if (twoPlay == 0){
               System.out.println("Player2 beat Player1!"); 
               lose1++;
               win2++;//Player2 chose rock - player2 wins
            }
            if (twoPlay == 1){
               System.out.println("Player1 beat Player2!");
               lose2++;
               win1++;//player2 chose paper - player1 wins
            }
            if (twoPlay == 2){
               System.out.println("Player1 and Player2 tie!"); 
               //player2 chose scissors - tie game
            }
         }//end if statements for personPlay = 2 (Scissors)
         //end //comparisons Player1 vs Player2
         System.out.println("Would you like to play again? 0=yes, 1=no");
         playChoice = UI.nextInt(2);
      }//end while loop for play

      //user decides not to play or decides to stop playing - Stats are given
      if (playChoice == 1){
         System.out.println("Ok let's play (again) sometime.");//game ended
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("We played " + game + " games.");//number of games played
         System.out.println("Player1 won " + win1 + " games, lost " + compWin + " games.");//Player1 wins and losses
         System.out.println("Player2 won " + win2 + " games, lost " + lose2 + " games.");//Player2 wins and losses
         System.out.println("I won " + compWin + " games and lost " + compLose + " games.");//computers wins and losses
         System.out.print("In terms of wins, ");

      //determine best player
      System.out.println("Across all games played, ");
      if (win1 > (win2 & compWin)){
         System.out.println("Player1 beat Player2 and I!");
      }   
      else if (win2 > (win1 & compWin)){
         System.out.println("Player2 beat Player1 and I!");
      }   
      else 
         System.out.println("I beat Player1 and Player2!");

      }//end while loop
   }//end method
}//end program
```

Comment: Why is this put on hold for "being to broad" or "good answers would be to long for this format". I already got my answer as I edited the questions saying -Solved-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional should be

```
if ((win1 > win2) && (win1 > compWin)){
     System.out.println("Player1 beat Player2 and I!");
  }   
  else if ((win2 > win1) && (win2 > compWin)){
     System.out.println("Player2 beat Player1 and I!");
  }   
  else 
     System.out.println("I beat Player1 and Player2!");

  }
```

because AND statement in java is "&&" not "&",
also your conditional checking is wrong

Comment: Thank you very much. So it must be a double comparison put into one condition if I would have to explain this to someone?

Comment: you have to compare win1 with both win2 and compWin, then compare the result of both comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (win1 > (win2 & compWin))
```

This should be

```
if (win1 > win2 && win1 > compWin)
```

And same thing for the `else if`.

The logical AND operator is `&&`. `&` is a bitwise AND, which is an entirely different operation. That's a somewhat advanced capability you won't be using just yet.

What you wrote is a common mistake where translating English directly into code doesn't work. `&&` and `||` don't work quite the same as "and" and "or" do in English.

(By the way, grammatically it should say "Player1 beat Player2 and me.")

Comment: Thank you very much. So it must be a double comparison put into one condition if I would have to explain this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a bitwise operator in your comparison. I don't think that is what you intended.

```
if (win1 > (win2 & compWin)){
   // if win2 = 14 and compWin = 9
   //     9 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000001001 (base 2)
   //    14 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000001110 (base 2)
   //            --------------------------------
   //14 & 9 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000001000 (base 2) = 8 (base 10)
   // if win2 = 14 and compWin = 0; 14 & 0 = 0
   System.out.println("Player1 beat Player2 and I!");
}
```

I think you meant to compare win1 to win2 and compWin using the logical && operator.

```
// Should be:
if(win1 > win2 && win1 > compWin) {
   System.out.println("Player1 beat Player2 and I!");
}
else if (win2 > win1 && win2 > compWin)){
   System.out.println("Player2 beat Player1 and I!");
}   
else 
   System.out.println("I beat Player1 and Player2!");
}
```

Logical expressions using && or || are evaluated on one side, then the other. If the left side is true, && the right side is true, return true; otherwise return false.